# Error with using decltype() in C++11 (creating opaque error message in gcc 4.7.0)

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, decltype

with the following code (a boiled-down version of my original code)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

template <typename> class A;                  // edit 1 following Mark & Matthieu
template <typename X> class A {
  X a;
  template <typename> friend class A;         // edit 1 following Mark & Matthieu
public:
  A(X x) : a(x) {}
  X get() const { return a; }                // edit 2 to avoid using A<Y>::a
  template <typename Y>
  auto diff(A<Y> const& y) const
    -> decltype(a - y.a)                       // original code causing error with gcc
    -> typename std::common_type<X, Y>::type  // alternative following Rook
    -> decltype(this->get() -                 // edit 3 not using A<X>::a
                y.get())                     // edit 2 not using A<Y>::a
  { return a - y.get(); }
};

template <typename X, typename Y>
inline auto dist(A<X> const& x, A<Y> const& y) -> decltype(std::abs(x.diff(y)))
{ return std::abs(x.diff(y)); }

int main()
{
  A<double> x(2.0), y(4.5);
  std::cout << " dist(x,y)=" << dist(x,y) << '\n'; // <-- error here
}
```

I get the following error with gcc 4.7.0:

> test.cc: In function `decltype (std::abs(x.diff(y))) dist(const A<X>&, const A<Y>&)` [with `X = double; Y = double; decltype (std::abs(x.diff(y))) = double`]’:
>
> test.cc:5:5: error: `double A<double>::a` is private
>
> highlighted line: error: within this context

This error message is obviously not very helpful. Is there an error in my code? Or is this a problem with the compiler?

**EDIT1**: the friend declaration didn't help.

**EDIT2**: avoiding using `A<Y>::a` didn't help either.

**EDIT3**: together with **EDIT2** finally **fixed the problem**. The `decltype()` in the definition of `dist()` requires the `decltype()` for `A<X>::diff()`, which in turn used `A<X>::a`, which is private in the first context.

**EDTI4**: Rook's suggestion of using `typename std::common_type<X,Y>::type` also works!

**EDIT5**: but see Jonathan Wakely's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055350/what-is-better-to-use-for-automatic-return-types-decltype-or-stdcommon-type#comment14465455_11055350)

Comment: Using gcc-4.3 your code also does not compile. See [this link](http://ideone.com/VSGxN) for the errors returned.

Comment: @PenguinCoder: gcc-4.3 doesn't support C++11 (aka C++0x).  This question is about gcc-4.7, which does.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield GCC 4.3 supports *some* C++11 features, while 4.7 supports *many* but not all features. See [GCC's C++11 support table](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html). Technically both have only "experimental" support.

Comment: GCC 4.3 is so old that no-one should be keeping it...

Comment: @JohnDibling: I would not care about MSVC in templated code, it does not implement two-phase lookup so fails to check a number of mishaps. The fact that Clang refuses it, however, is a red-herring.

Comment: Compiles in clang++ (with the friend declaration). Is the error after adding the friend declaration exactly the same?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: is the `friend` declaration necessary ? If checking is differed to instantiation and `X` and `Y` are the same type, it seems like a spurious error.

Comment: One more question for you all... would `std::common_type<X, Y>` be a more appropriate type for `diff()` here? It _looks_ like it should be, but I was unable to get it compiling in either gcc 4.4 or vs2010...

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Not really, it is not necessary. I just did not try both versions (just copied/pasted the latest). I have tried without the friend declaration and it compiles fine

Comment: Ahh, I wasn't using the `typename` magic, hence where I was going wrong. Glad you managed to get it working!

Comment: @Rook: Nice pick! I think it is safe to assume then than this is a gcc bug, since there is no reason an expression refused in `decltype` should later be allowed in the body. It's inconsistent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Gcc [appears to have a bug](http://ideone.com/NpF0F) where trailing return types on template member functions are not treated as within the class's scope.

This bug causes gcc to fail when instantiating the template member function `auto diff(A<Y> const&y) const -> decltype(a-y.a)` because `a` is private and gcc thinks private members are inaccessible here.

---

The code builds fine with clang and VC++, and I don't see anything trying to access `A<double>::a` outside `A<double>`, so it looks like a gcc bug to me.

Others have mentioned that `A<X>` and `A<Y>` are different classes, but that's not the case here, both are `A<double>`. I believe that means that friendship is not necessary in this case, although to work in the general case `A<X>` does need to be friends with other specializations of A.

Specifically, `a` in `y.a` is a dependent name so it cannot be looked up until `A<Y>` is known. At that point lookup is done, the accessibility is tested and it should be found that `A<double>` does have access to `A<double>::a`.

Here's the exact code I compiled in both clang (svn-3.2) and VC++11 (Since I'm using clang on Windows I can't `#include <iostream>`)

```
#include <cmath>

template<typename X> class A {
  X a;
public:
  A(X x) : a(x) {}
  template<typename Y>
  auto diff(A<Y> const&y) const -> decltype(a-y.a)
  { return a-y.a; }
};

template<typename X, typename Y>
inline auto dist(A<X> const&x, A<Y> const&y) -> decltype(std::abs(x.diff(y)))
{ return std::abs(x.diff(y)); }

int main()
{
  A<double> x(2.0), y(4.5);
  return (int) dist(x,y);
}
```

This code results in [build errors on gcc 4.5](http://ideone.com/2CtBE) similar to what you describe.

Replacing

```
auto diff(A<Y> const&y) const -> decltype(a-y.a)
```

with

```
auto diff(A<Y> const&y) const -> typename std::common_type<X,Y>::type
```

causes the code to [work on gcc 4.5](http://ideone.com/La4mT).

This indicates to me a bug where gcc is failing to treat trailing return types as inside the class's scope. [Some testing reveals](http://ideone.com/NpF0F) that the trailing return type must be on a template function to trigger the bug.

Comment: No, see other answers.  It's just that `A<X>` and `A<Y>` are different types, so they cannot access each other's private members

Comment: Ah, interesting. I would say that `diff` is ill-defined because it cannot access `y.a` in general (unless `Y` happens to be `X`); but I would not bet whether it should be diagnosed at declaration or instantiation.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I believe that if there are _no_ legal instantiations then it's ill-formed and can be diagnosed at declaration or instantiation. However there are legal instantiations and so I believe it should only be diagnosed on those instantiations which are not legal.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Obviously templates can't be considered ill-formed simply because there's _some_ intantiation that is illegal. This template simply requires that `y.a` be legal, just like `template<typename T> void foo(T t) { t.bar(); }` requires that `t.bar()` be legal.

Comment: @bames53: yes, this seems better. After all if we were talking about anything else than `A<Y>` *some* instantiations of `A` could be `friend` and not others, so the check during the declaration phase would be way too hard to get right.

Comment: @MatthieuM. and not only that, but `A<Y>` could refer to some explicit specialization of A where `A<Y>::a` is public.

Comment: @MatthieuM. In case you're interested I believe I have narrowed down exactly what GCC is getting wrong here.

Comment: @bames53 you should write a but report, will you?

Comment: @Walter yeah, I don't have 4.7 to test with. I suspect that the OP is running into the same bug but where it requires a bit more code to trigger. Since I can't test with the latest version I'm not planning to file anything.

Answer (score 8):

There is an error with your code:

```
template<typename Y>
  auto diff(A<Y> const&y) const -> decltype(a-y.a)
  { return a-y.a; }
```

Here, `A<Y>` is a different type, so `A<X>` cannot see it's `a` data member. Only `A<Y>` can see `A<Y>::a`.

**Edit**: that said, in your particular case, `X` and `Y` are both `double`, so I would naively expect that to compile. Note that in the best of cases, this construction should only compile when `X` and `Y` are the same, which may not be what you want.

Comment: Since it compiles correctly in VS2010, is it then a bug in VS2010?

Comment: This was my first thought, but I'm a bit skeptical, because in his particular in case (nevermind, your edit says exactly what I was going to say)

Comment: @Patrick I wouldn't assume that because it compiles on VS2010 then it follows that the bug is in GCC. But right now I cannot say for sure whether it is a bug or not. This stuff is all quite new...

Answer (score 2):

Your function `auto diff(A<Y> const& y)` access the `private` variable `A::a` from outside the class in your `decltype` statement.

Your `A::a` should be `public` if you want to use it the way you do in your `diff` function.

EDIT: it seems the friendship solution is much better suited for this problem, then just making it public.

Comment: I believe trailing return types are inside the classes scope.

Comment: a getter is the same as just making it public, and I don't appreciate your nasty comments

Comment: A getter is not the same as making it public, as you still don't have write access.  But neither of those options should be considered in this case unless there is no other way around the problem, as it would be a change in the interface of the class.

Comment: neither the friendship solution nor the other solution whereby I avoid using `A<Y>::a` in `A<X>` helped, see edits

Answer (score 2):

`auto diff(A<Y> const&y) const -> decltype(a-y.a)` is the problem; regardless of anything else, if `X` and `Y` are different types, `A<X>` and `A<Y>` are different types and cannot peek at each other's privates. Templates are not covariant!

The specific error here might be an eccentricity of GCC (in that it doesn't spot that `X` is the same type as `Y`) but the more general case where you might be trying to diff two different types (and why else would you have a separate template type in your diff function?) will never work, regardless of compiler.

Comment: While you were correct about the line which contains the problem, you were wrong about the reason. It's the usage of `a` as well as `y.a` that caused the problem, not the access of `A<Y>::a` from `A<X>`, but the access of both from `decltype()` in the global function `dist()`.

Comment: Yeah, nested issues. It was an impressively complex problem!

Answer (score 0):

As I have figured out by now (see also the edits to the question) what the problem was. It turns out that all answers (sofar) didn't solve the (full) problem.

Essentially, the evaluation of the `decltype` expression for the global function required eventually the private member `A<X>::a` (through its occurrence in the `decltype` expression of `A<x>::diff()`). This opens the next question about what the standard says about this.