# What is better to use for automatic return types: decltype or std::common_type<>::type (if possible)?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits, decltype

As answer to my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052842/error-with-using-decltype-in-c11-creating-opaque-error-message-in-gcc-4-7-0) it was suggested to use, when possible, `std::common_type<X,Y>::type` in the declaration of automatic return types instead of my original `decltype()`. However, doing so I ran into problems (using gcc 4.7.0). Consider the following simple code

```
template<typename> class A;
template<typename X> class A {
  X a[3];
  template <typename> friend class A;
public:
  A(X a0, X a1, X a2) { a[0]=a0; a[1]=a1; a[2]=a2; }
  X operator[](int i) const { return a[i]; }
  X operator*(A const&y) const          // multiplication 0: dot product with self
  { return a[0]*y[0] + a[1]*y[1] + a[2]*y[2]; }
  template<typename Y>
  auto operator*(A<Y> const&y) const -> // multiplication 1: dot product with A<Y>
#ifdef USE_DECLTYPE
    decltype((*this)[0]*y[0])
#else
    typename std::common_type<X,Y>::type
#endif
  { return a[0]*y[0] + a[1]*y[1] + a[2]*y[2]; }
  template<typename Y>
  auto operator*(Y s) const ->          // multiplication 2: with scalar
#ifdef USE_DECLTYPE
    A<decltype((*this)[0]*s)>
#else
    A<typename std::common_type<X,Y>::type>
#endif
  { return A<decltype((*this)[0]*s)>(s*a[0],s*a[1],s*a[2]); }
};

int main()
{
  A<double> x(1.2,2.0,-0.4), y(0.2,4.4,5.0);
  A<double> z = x*4;
  auto dot = x*y;           // <-- 
  std::cout<<" x*4="<<z[0]<<' '<<z[1]<<' '<<z[2]<<'\n'
           <<" x*y="<<dot<<'\n';
}
```

when `USE_DECLTYPE` is `#defined`, the code compiles and runs fine with gcc 4.7.0. But otherwise, the line indicated in `main()` calls the multiplaction 2, which seems weird if not wrong. Could this possibly be a consequence/side effect of using `std::common_type` or is it a bug with gcc?

I always thought that the return type has no bearing on which of a multitude of fitting template functions is chosen...

Comment: `std::common_type<X, Y>` may well make some assumptions about how `X` ad `Y` behave, and is defined in C++. `decltype` on the other hand is a special language feature, and so I feel it would have fewer problems in strange circumstances. I'll have a play with your code and see what happens.

Comment: So, having flailed around with GCC4.4 and VS2010 a bit... I've come to the conclusion that I have no idea, but that `std::common_type` gives significantly nastier compilation errors than `decltype` when things go wrong. Make of that what you will.

Comment: @Rook thanks. I'd like to know what the standard says -- any idea anybody?

Comment: @Rook, you should probably get a newer version of GCC if you want to use and give advice on C++11

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The suggestion to use `common_type` is bogus.

The problem using `decltype` you had in your other question was simply a [GCC bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52816).

The problem you have in this question when using `common_type` is because `std::common_type<X, Y>::type` tells you the type that you would get from the expression:

```
condition ? std::declval<X>() : std::declval<Y>()
```

i.e. what type an `X` and a `Y` can both be converted to.

In general that has absolutely nothing to do with the result of `x * y`, if `X` and `Y` have an overloaded `operator*` that returns a completely different type.

In your specific case, you have the expression `x*y` where both variables are type `A<double>`.  Overload resolution tries to check each overloaded `operator*` to see if it's valid.  As part of overload resolution it instantiates this member function template:

```
template<typename Y>
    auto operator*(Y s) const ->
    A<typename std::common_type<X,Y>::type>;
```

With `A<double>` substituted for the template parameter `Y`.  That tries to instantiate `common_type<double, A<double>>` which is not valid, because the expression

```
condition ? std::declval<double>() : std::declval< A<double> >()
```

is not valid, because you cannot convert `A<double>` to `double` or vice versa, or to any other common type.

The error doesn't happen because that overloaded `operator*` is *called*, it happens because the template must be instantiated in order to decide which operator should be called, and the act of instantiating it causes the error.  The compiler never gets a far as deciding which operator to call, the error stops it before it gets that far.

So, as I said, the suggestion to use `common_type` is bogus, it prevents SFINAE from disabling the member function templates that don't match the argument types (formally, SFINAE doesn't work here because the substitution error happens outside the "immediate context" of the template, i.e. it happens inside the definition of `common_type` not in the function signature, where SFINAE applies.)

---

It's permitted to specialize `std::common_type` so it knows about types without implicit conversions, so you *could* specialize it so that `common_type<double, A<double>>::type` is valid and produces the type `double`, like so:

```
namespace std {
  template<typename T>
    struct common_type<T, A<T>> { typedef T type; };
}
```

**Doing so would be a very bad idea!**  What `common_type` is supposed to give is the answer to "what type can both these types safely be converted to?". The specialization above subverts it to give the answer to "what is the result of multiplying these types?" which is a completely different question!  It would be as foolish as specializing `is_integral<std::string>` to be true.

If you want the answer to "what is the type of a general expression such as *expr* ?" then use `decltype(expr)`, that's what it's for!

Comment: ok, `std::common_type` is not a good idea here. But it shouldn't have any implications for which of the overloaded `operator*` is chosen, should it?